# list.files() lists files multiple times

Tags: r, regex

I am using the code below to list files with the given pattern, however all the specified files are listed twice. I do not understand why?

I am gathering files from the working directory which has subfolders in it therefore I am using recursive = TRUE. The duplication is caused by returning the file path in two different ways which lead to the same file: for example: "100/main/day0.xls" and "main/day0.xls".

```
list.files(pattern = "0.xls$", recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE)
```

Comment: perhaps `pattern = "0\\.xls$"`

Comment: No it did not solve it. But thank you for the tip.

Comment: I think you need `full.names = TRUE` instead of `include.dirs = TRUE`.

Comment: I can't repro with `list.files(path=my_path, pattern = "0\\.xls$", recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE)`. Files are only listed once. Note: I am using Windows, R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30).

Comment: You are right. I found the issue. I was given the folders and did not know that a hidden duplicate folder was placed in the working directory. That caused the duplicates. Is there a way to circumvent this incidents in the code? So hidden files are disregarded? Many thanks for your answers